# Standard Uniform Dist to Discrete Uniform [a, b]

Tags: random, numbers, generator, uniform

I can not for the life of me remember or find the formula for transforming the standard uniform distribution to a discrete uniform distribution with a range of [a, b].  What I'm looking for specifically is a discrete uniform random number generator that produces numbers in the range of [a, b] and I need it to be a function of Math.random() where Math.random() is a continuous uniform distribution with a range of [0, 1)

If you know that transformation I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I think I may have gotten it. `(int)(a + Math.random() * (b - a + 1))`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) of [0, 1] to [a, b].

So where `x` is in [0,1] you'd want to transform it to `a + x × (b - a)` then round the result. You need to round and not to simply cast or your distribution will be slightly skewed.

Rounding with a cast can be done by adding 0.5 before casting.